# AJAX HTTP Request and Python web server HTTP response return

Tags: python, ajax

I'm just new in integrating ajax http request and return a python webserver http response. I really no have an idea how to use it.

For example my web page is on another IP . like 192.168.1.1 and i will get a data or a response from 192.168.1.2
then on my view:

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://192.168.1.2:8012/",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data) {
             alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

now on my python web server

```
import string,cgi,time
from os import curdir, sep
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import MySQLdb
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import E as buildE
import urllib

global db, cnn

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","schema" )
cnn = db.cursor()


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        global cnn, sql

        self.wfile.write("Cannot GET "+self.path)
        print "test"
        self.send_response(200, "testing")
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'xml')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("testing")


    def do_POST(self):
        global rootnode
        try:
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
            if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                query=cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
            self.send_response(301)

            self.end_headers()
            upfilecontent = query.get('upfile')
            print "filecontent", upfilecontent[0]
            self.wfile.write("<HTML>POST OK.<BR><BR>");
            self.wfile.write(upfilecontent[0]);

        except :
            pass



def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8012), MyHandler)
        print 'started httpserver...'
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down server'
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I just want a returned data from the webserver. But i think im doing it wrong.

Comment: So, what do you see? What errors do you get?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's not working bro

Comment: How am I supposed to help? What does "it's not working" mean? What do you see? What errors do you get? What is happening that shouldn't, or isn't happening that should?

Comment: @DanielRoseman on my server it does print the "test" but it doesnt return on my ajax and print the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't send data to self.wfile before sending ALL headers. And maybe you should send a 'Content-length' header to let your page know when it must stop waiting for data. Something like this:

```
data="Cannot GET "+self.path
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header('Content-type','text/xml')
self.send_header('Content-length',str(len(data))
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(data)
```